# How to Slide numbers in an array?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am trying to slide numbers into an array
for example, my array `8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1` and when the code finishes the loop, it should be `1,8,7,6,5,4,3,2`, I am not sure how to do that

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
    ARR DB 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 

.CODE
.STARTUP
   MOV CX,8
   MOV SI ,7   

 LOP:
   MOV AL ,ARR[SI]  
   MOV BL ,ARR[SI-1]

   MOV ARR[SI], BL
   MOV ARR[SI-1], AL

   DEC SI


LOOP LOP

.EXIT
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem here, the algorithm or the assembly language? Do you know how to do it in C, Java, C#, Haskell, Python or any other language of choice?

Comment: A more efficient way of presenting the data in this way without reordering it is to simply use an array index with a modulus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that would drag last element thorough whole array:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
    ARR DB 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 

.CODE
.STARTUP

 MOV CX , 7           ; here: one less ( you only shift size-1 elements) 
 MOV SI , 7   

 LOP:
   MOV  AL,ARR[SI-1]
   XCHG AL, ARR[SI]
   MOV  ARR[SI-1], AL
   DEC SI
 LOOP LOP

.EXIT
```

Can't possibly imagine why you need that kind of algorithm, but still.

Comment: actually, that's i need. Thanks for your help

Comment: @muco this is very inefficient implementation, for large arrays with few read acesses it would make sense to modify index by offset+modulus (what David Hoelzer suggests), for many read accesses and rare array "sliding" it would make sense to load the last element elsewhere, then "memmove" the array (probably with `rep movsb`, but this could be further optimized if you have full control over allocation of array, so you can align it and use `movsd` instead or even new SSE/AVX/... instructions), and put the stored last element at first position. This "bubbling" of value is only easy to read.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%"  Donald Knuth